# Throwing an exception for a char const*

Tags: c++

I have some if, else_if, else blocks of code for different user input. The else at the end is for an invalid entry from the user. This is all part of a try block.

In the case the user makes an invalid entry I have to throw an exception. My prof already has this code prepared for the catch:

```
catch (char const* errormsg ) // for invalid item case
    {code goes here }
```

Right now my else statement just looks like this:

```
else {
throw item;
}
```

I'm new to exception handling. Can somebody explain what I need to throw for the catch to catch it?

Comment: Why do you apparently believe that you need to throw anything other than what gets caught, a `const char *`?

Comment: In future, if you have a question about your assignment or your professor's code, _ask your professor_. That's what they're there for. You are literally paying them to teach you the basics. We don't want to teach people the basics. Generally.

Comment: *The else at the end is for an invalid entry from the user* -- A user having fat fingers and entering wrong information is *not* a reason to be throwing an exception.  Exceptions should be reserved for those times for those *exceptional* cases, i.e. events that should have never happened, but happen anyway.

Comment: That is not true. It is perfectly reasonable to use exceptions for handling bad input. You will repeatedly encounter people with amazingly narrow definitions of the term "exceptional" and who, as a consequence, require that you make your code as complicated as possible just for the sake of "not doing that" with no further rationale; you are safe to ignore them.

Comment: In other words, "exceptional" and "rare" are not the same thing.

Comment: C++ exceptions are so heavy-handed (with the common zero-cost model) though I'd lean to "rare" for "exceptional".

Comment: I try to not have C++ code transmogrify into something looking like Java, where exceptions are thrown for practically anything.

Comment: Good, nobody suggested that.

Answer (score 4):

Since the code is designed to catch `const char*`s, and the argument has been called `errormsg`, it seems like the intent was for the exception object to be a C-style string containing the error message.

A string literal fits the bill:

```
throw "This is a description of the problem";
```

Note that this is bad practice; you should throw something of a descriptive type that derives from `std::exception` as a matter of convention.

Comment: The _why_ behind the convention would motivate readers to comply.

Comment: :-) Fair enough, but this **will** eventuallly be the accepted answer so why not point it out (was my thought).